# Safari browser for windows support ECMAScript 2016(ECMAScript 7) or not?

Tags: javascript, windows, safari, ecmascript-2016, safari-windows

I'm currently working on developing a website using ECMAScript 2016 and it works just fine on Google Chrome and other browsers but when I run that website on the Safari browser for Windows(Version 5.1.7), it doesn't work and getting some errors on my Azure DevOps dashboard.

So, can anyone please confirm that to me that whether the Safari browser for Windows(Version 5.1.7) supports ECMAScript 2016(ECMAScript 7) or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari 5.1 was released sometime around [2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_5_2) or [2012](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202479). Apple has [not supported Safari for Windows for many years now](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/94010), although links to (ancient) installers that work on Windows are still findable.

There's no way such an old browser would support ES2016 - its specification was finalized 4 years after the browser was released.

If you want to test a site on more modern versions of Safari and you don't own a Mac, you can try [browserstack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825599) or use a virtual PC.

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/macos-windows-10-virtual-machine/