# How to resolve client-side error? Message and error appears only on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I'm using context api and I can't access this error, on my cell phone and computer it apparently works normally, but on some iOS and even Android devices there is this problem. As only the image was sent and I don't have a mac book hahah I don't know how to solve this!!
By recommendation I am using 'use client'; at the beginning of components that use context api

application error: a client-side exception has ocurred(see the browser console for more information)

https://relvis-delivery-2-0.vercel.app/

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use the same device than the user**, you can take a look at [these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825599/testing-web-application-on-mac-safari-when-i-dont-own-a-mac)

**If you can't reproduce** the problem when using the same device than the user:

1. I suggest to install some application monitoring tool like Sentry, Firebase (free).
   It will sends all javascript errors to a dashboard.
2. If you don't want to install anything and do it by yourself, you can use [React error boundaries](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) to catch errors and send them to a dedicated endpoint in your API, then create your own dashboard.